How to fix "deprecated get_page_by_title" in WordPress
I'm was using the function get_page_by_title() in my WordPress project, but as it's deprecated, I tried to turn off WP_DEBUG, but it's still not working.
My language folder structure:
-----language
---------ja.json
---------en.json
File ja.json
{
    "page-title": "page title - ja",
}

File en.json
{
    "page-title": "page title",
}

and I use get_page_by_title() like:
$pageId = get_page_by_title(lang('page-title'))->ID;

My approach is to use WP_Query, to replace get_page_by_title() like:
function get_page_id_by_title($title) {
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'name',
                'value' => $title,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        ),
    ));

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $page_id = get_the_ID();
        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $page_id;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

But it's not working. I need a function that works the same way as the deprecated WordPress function get_page_by_title().
